# Groovy XmlSlurper: get value of attribute that has an associated namespace

Tags: xml, groovy, namespaces

I have an XML document that contains attributes with qualified names. I want to get the attribute value using XmlSlurper, but trying to access the attribute without specifying the namespace does not work (below is a minimal example).

```groovy
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(
'''<root xmlns:ex="http://example.com">
     <one ex:a1="uno!"/>
     <ex:two>Some text!</ex:two>
   </root>''' )

assert rootNode.one[0].@a1.text() == 'uno!'
```

`rootNode.one[0].@a1.text()` will yield an empty string. If using `rootNode.one[0].'@ex:a1'.text()` we get the correct value, but this is dependent on the namespace prefix used in the document - and that can't be relied upon to be the same for other documents, the associated namespace is what matters.

**So the question is:**
How can XmlSlurper be used to access an attribute value of an attribute that has an associated namespace without the need to specify the namespace prefix?
(it would be OK if supplying the whole namespace is needed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that accessing an attribute with an associated namespace can't be done without specifying such namespace. Otherwise, only the "local part of the name" would be used for the map holding the attributes, leading to situations like [this old bug (groovy 1.7.5)](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4637).

Maybe the best way to do that is to use [`groovy.xml.Namespace`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/xml/Namespace.html) and use it to access the attribute:

```groovy
import groovy.xml.Namespace

def xml = '''
<root xmlns:ex="http://example.com">
    <one ex:a1="uno!"/>
    <ex:two>Some text!</ex:two>
</root>'''
def ns = new Namespace('http://example.com', 'ex')

def slurper = new XmlSlurper(false, true)
def slurped = slurper.parseText(xml)
assert 'uno!' == slurped.one[0].attributes()[ns.a1.toString()]

def parser = new XmlParser(false, true)
def parsed = parser.parseText(xml)
assert 'uno!' == parsed.one[0].attributes()[ns.a1]
```

Comment: I agree that accessing attributes w/o namespace can lead to messy situations, but sometimes it's convenient to work namespace independent. With XmlSlurper it's unexpected that it behaves so differently for elements and attributes - `slurped.two[0]` will yield the element with the associated namespace, while it does not do the same for attributes.

Comment: I agree with you on that... It's a bit misleading that XmlSlurper behaves differently for elements and attributes. Besides, you can create a XmlSlurper with `namespaceAware=false`, but in that case, the key of the attributes' map is `ex:a1`   instead of `{http://example.com}a1`.

Answer (score 4):

A cleaner method might be to use `find` and `localPart` with `XmlParser`:

```
def rootNode = new XmlParser().parseText(
'''<root xmlns:ex="http://example.com">
     <one ex:a1="uno!"/>
     <ex:two>Some text!</ex:two>
   </root>''' )

rootNode.one[0].attributes().find { it.key.localPart == 'a1' }?.value
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found is making use of the possibility to access the attributes via the representation of a GPathResult as [Node](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/Node.html).

The working example looks like this:

```groovy
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(
'''<root xmlns:ex="http://example.com">
     <one ex:a1="uno!"/>
     <ex:two>Some text!</ex:two>
   </root>''' )

// map of attributes, or null
def oneAttrs = rootNode.one[0].nodeIterator().next()?.attributes()
assert oneAttrs
// retrieve attribute by qualified name
assert oneAttrs['{http://example.com}a1'] == 'uno!'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:versionCode="500" android:versionName="5.0.0" package="com.my.package"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal" >
...
</manifest >
```

parsing attr with namespace and without:

```
def parsedXml = (new XmlSlurper()).parse(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
def pkg_name = parsedXml.@package.text()
def pkg_ver = parsedXml.@'android:versionName'
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve the problem. As mentioned in the question we get the correct value like that, but it is dependent on the namespace prefix used in the document - and that can't be relied upon to be the same for other documents, the associated namespace is what matters.

So with that approach one would need to determine the namespace prefix first. But as the prefix for a namespace can be defined and overridden on any XML element, this is not so easy.